# The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple learning app with hive..

here I want to store all deleted expense record into separate file,(box) so that I can get it restored on request..

I don't want to store deleted records in same file,

I checked history questions regarding this issue but not getting exact reason.

concept is simple to create a another file with same object type...in future I would go with backup and restore ....

here is my code

```
class Boxes
{
  static Box<ExpenseModel> getExpenseRecords()
  {
    return Hive.box<ExpenseModel>('expenserecords');
  }

  static Box<ExpenseModel> getDeletedRecords()
  {
    return Hive.box<ExpenseModel>('deletedrecords');
  }
}
```

main file

```
void main() async
{

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var dir_path=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(dir_path.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(ExpenseModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(CategoryModelAdapter());

  await Hive.openBox<ExpenseModel>('expenserecords');
  await Hive.openBox<ExpenseModel>('deletedrecords');



  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and delete function

```
Expanded(
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<ExpenseModel>>(
                valueListenable:Boxes.getExpenseRecords().listenable(),

                builder: (context, box, _) {
                  //todo study which index is exactly taken
                  var data = box.values
                      .toList();
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final exp = data[index];
                        return ExpenseCard(
                          exp: exp,
                          ondelete: () {

                            final rcyclebox=Boxes.getDeletedRecords();
                            rcyclebox.add(exp);//

                            exp.delete();
                            //this delete method belongs to hiveobject
                          },
                          onedit: () {
                          },
                          ontoogle: (){
                            exp.isexpense=!exp.isexpense;
                            box.putAt(index, exp);
                          },

                        );
                      });
                },
              )
```

expense model classs

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class ExpenseModel extends HiveObject
{
  @HiveField(0)
  String title;
  @HiveField(1)
  CategoryModel category;
  @HiveField(2)
  int amount;
  @HiveField(3)
  bool isexpense;
  ExpenseModel({required this.title,required this.category,required this.amount,required this.isexpense});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting objects from Hive and saving the **same object instance** (*after modification of course, but the object reference is the same*). Hive knows this is the same object and complains that I can't store the same thing again. So you will have to create a new object instance. You can create a **copywith** method that returns a new object.